# Share ViewModel used by calling Fragment to DialogFragment using by viewModels

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, android-ktx

I have a `SearchFragment` with the following code.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SearchFragment :
    Fragment(),
    View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    private var _binding: FragSearchBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding as FragSearchBinding
    private val viewmodel by viewModels<SearchViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    )
        : View {
        _binding = FragSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.fragSearchSearchResultFilter.setOnClickListener(this)
        return binding.root
    }

    ...

    private fun showFilterDialog() {
        val dialog = FilterBottomSheetDialogFragment.newInstance()
        dialog.show(parentFragmentManager, "filter_bsd_tag")
    }
    ...
}
```

I am showing a `FilterBottomSheetDialogFragment` using that `SearchFragment`. I want to pass the ViewModel of `SearchFragment` to the `DialogFragment`. I have this code for my `FilterBottomSheetDialogFragment`.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FilterBottomSheetDialogFragment :
    BottomSheetDialogFragment(),
    View.OnClickListener {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FilterBottomSheetDialogFragment()
        private const val TAG_SELECTION_DIALOG = "tag_selection_dialog"
    }

    private var _binding: BsdFilterBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding as BsdFilterBinding
    private val viewmodel: SearchViewModel = ???
}
```

I have tried

```
private val viewmodel by viewModels<SearchViewModel>(ownerProducer = { this.requireParentFragment() })
```

The above doesn't work as it just creates a new instance of ViewModel.

I also tried

```
private val viewmodel: SearchViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(requireParentFragment()).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
}
```

The above doesn't work with the error saying that the `SearchViewModel` instance cannot be created. My `SearchViewModel` has this constructor.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val courseRepository: CourseRepository
) : ViewModel()
```

How can I pass the `SearchViewModel` to the `DialogFragment` without using the constructor parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mistake here is actually the fragment manager you're using when showing your dialog. Currently you're using the *parent* fragment manager, whereas your dialog should exist as a child fragment of the fragment it is being shown from.

So you should be using:

```
dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "filter_bsd_tag")
```

which will then ensure that

```
viewModels<SearchViewModel>(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() })
```

refers to the `SearchFragment`.

Comment: It's working, but I'd like to ask something. What's the correlation between the _fragment manager_ and the _parent fragment_? Is _parent fragment_ determined by the _fragment manager_?

Comment: Say we had `ParentFragment` which then has `SearchFragment` as its child. When you show a dialog from `SearchFragment` with the *parent fragment manager*, the dialog becomes a child of `ParentFragment`. So then the dialog's parent is NOT `SearchFragment`, it's `ParentFragment`.

Comment: So this could also technically be 'fixed' by using `requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment()`. Then the two view models would both be scoped to the same fragment, just not `SearchFragment`.